# Regression Analysis for Proportional Data

Tags: regression, correlation, proportion, paired-data, percentage

I am going to try to simplify the context of my analysis into an apples/oranges scenario.

I have 30 baskets, each with 10 fruits. The 10 fruits are made up of a number of apples and oranges.

Each fruit also has a number of dots on them.

I want to run a correlation between the proportion of apples in the baskets and the proportion of dots on the apples. For example, Basket 1 has 30% apples and the apples have 40% of the dots on the fruits in the basket. Basket 2 has 60% apples and the apples have 20% of the dots on the fruits in the basket, and so on. I want to also run the same correlation with the oranges.

I want to see whether there is a relationship between the number of apples in the baskets and the number of dots on the apples across the 30 baskets. If I run the regression with just the proportion of apples, I get a different correlation than when running a correlation with the oranges. I was wondering what kind of regression would be appropriate for comparing paired/linked proportional data like this?

Comment: Are you interested in the total number of dots on the apples, or the proportion of dots on the apples? How are the dots generated on the apples? e.g. is there a limit of the number of the dots on an apple?

Comment: I am interested in the proportion of dots on the apples (e.g., there are a total of 60 dots across the 10 fruits in Basket 1, and 40% of the dots are on the apples). It's unimportant how the dots are generated on the apples, and there are no limit to the dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your direction of using a linear regression is appealing even though it has an obvious limitation (of not being limited to $[0,1]$. We can change it though to fit your analysis.

> I want to see whether there is a relationship between the number of apples in the baskets and the number of dots on the apples across the 30 baskets

So, assuming we want to estimate the apples-regression. That is, to find the relationship between the number of apples in the basket (or, the proportion of apples in each basket), and the *proportion* of dots assigned them (of all the dots of all the fruits in the basket). Let's specify the task at hand as if we want to estimate the total number of points, so we can use a Poisson Regression model, which is a form of GLM model.

> Poisson Regression models are best used for modeling events where the outcomes are counts. Or, more specifically, count data: discrete data with non-negative integer values that count something, like the number of times an event occurs during a given timeframe or the number of people in line at the grocery store.
> Count data can also be expressed as rate data, since the number of times an event occurs within a timeframe can be expressed as a raw count (i.e. "In a day, we eat three meals") or as a rate ("We eat at a rate of 0.125 meals per hour"). [[here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-poisson-regression-in-r/#:%7E:text=A%20Poisson%20Regression%20model%20is,form%20by%20some%20unknown%20parameters.)]

I won't delve into Poisson Regression, as the link I attached includes a better and clearer introduction. Instead, let's discuss the modeling part. You want to specify a regression model that estimates the proportion of dots assigned to apples in the basket. Therefore, $y_i$ is this proportion, for basket $i$, and is calculated by $\dfrac{N^{apples}_{i}}{N^{oranges}_{i}}$, where $N$ is the number of dots.
Next, you want as a predictor the number of apples in basket $i$, $X_{i}$. I don't think we want to add a per-basket fixed effect because we aren't interested in the average number of dots per apple *within* the basket, but we definitely want to adjust our error rates to allow for correlation between fruits in the basket. Luckily, the `glm` package is quite general, and allow for clustered regression errors, see te documentation [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/miceadds/html/lm.cluster.html).

Comment: Thanks! How would a Poisson Regression differ from a Beta Regression, which is also used for proportional data?

Comment: What if I wanted to run a regression to see whether the dominant fruit in the basket also has the most dots? So for instance, in some baskets, apples dominate, while in other baskets, oranges dominate. So instead of apples vs. oranges, I would instead look at dominant vs. non-dominant fruit.

Comment: If the above answers your question, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: (To mark answer as an answer you need to click on the V button)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two is in their assumption of the distribution of $y$. Poisson regression assumes that $y$ is the result of a count, but it can also handle rates. Beta regression assumes that $y$ is distributed according to Beta distribution. In Poisson regression, the coefficients represent the logarithm of the ratio of the mean count for a one-unit increase in the predictor variable. In Beta regression, the coefficients represent the logarithm of the ratio of the mean proportion for a one-unit increase in the predictor variable. It sounds like they both may be valid in your case.
Regarding your second question:

> What if I wanted to run a regression to see whether the dominant fruit in the basket also has the most dots? So for instance, in some baskets, apples dominate, while in other baskets, oranges dominate. So instead of apples vs. oranges, I would instead look at dominant vs. non-dominant fruit. –

In that case, you may want to reparametrize your regression. Your current definition isn't clear, as you did not define what is dominant nor what "has the most dots" mean. Do you mean that

- if there are more oranges than apples in a basket, THEN oranges *on average* have more dots? or
- if there are more oranges than apples in a basket, THEN it is more likely that the fruit with the most dots in the basket is an orange?

Comment: For my second question about the dominant fruit, I meant the latter. If there are more oranges in a basket, then it is also likely to have more dots. If there are more apples in a basket, then it is likely to have more dots. I no longer care, in this case, about apples or oranges, but I only care about whether the more dominant fruit in a basket will also have more dots.

Comment: Then for the second point, your dependent variable would be a dummy variable that gets the value of 1 if the fruit with the most dots is an orange and 0 if it is an apple. Your predictor would now be the portion of oranges (make sure to be consistent with your notations, if orange is the positive class, then it has to be that way for the independent variable as well). Then you should use logistic regression, again, I recommend you cluster the error terms for different baskets.